# Proper use of strongSelf / weakSelf in nested dispatch_after blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have a complicated launch and I need to present and dismiss multiple view controllers. I have this bit of code where I need to use delays in presentation; I was wondering if my use of `strongSelf` / `weakSelf` was proper in the following code with these `dispatch_after` blocks, or if there are improvements that I should make to the code. I know it's outdated Objective-C, I am working with an old, large code base.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//CURRENT
    
    __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    
    [strongSelf presentViewController:strongSelf.coverVC animated:NO completion:^{
        
        [strongSelf showWindowWithImage:NO];
        
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            
            __strong typeof(self) strongSelf2 = weakSelf;

            [strongSelf2 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

                strongSelf2.coverVC = nil;
                [strongSelf2 hideWindow];
            }];
        });
    }];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a bit curious, possibly written by someone who did not entirely understand the purpose of the `weakSelf` pattern, much less the more complicated `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern. Admittedly, these can be daunting to new programmers, and when Objective-C programmers first encounter blocks and strong reference cycles, they often start sprinkling weak references everywhere in their code. This looks suspiciously like that.

So, let’s step back: We use `weakSelf` pattern in one of two scenarios:

1. It is possible that `self` (the view controller) might be dismissed before the `dispatch_after` fires in 0.1 seconds; or
2. The use of the non-weak `self` might result in a strong reference cycle.

In this case, the first seems exceedingly unlikely (but we’d need to know more about the UI to be positive) and the second doesn’t seem applicable at all, as there is no apparent strong reference cycle risk here.

Setting that aside, let’s discuss those scenarios where you would further complicate that `weakSelf` pattern with an additional `strongSelf` inside it (or two, in this case). We do either when:

1. We need to use that “weak self” reference in some context where a null value would cause an error; or
2. You want to protect yourself against race conditions where you are doing steps A and B and “self” might conceivably become null in the intervening period, but that it is important that if you do A that you also do B.

Again, I am not sure if either of those scenarios apply here. It feels appears that the original programmer was reflexively inserting `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern in their asynchronous patterns, possibly not understanding whether it was actually needed or not.

---

Bottom line, when dealing with a large legacy codebase, I am not sure I would waste any time on this particular code snippet.

To my eye, the entire usage of `weakSelf` looks completely unnecessary, but before you excise all of these `weakSelf`, `strongSelf`, and `strongSelf2` references, you would want to make sure that (a) there are no strong reference cycle risks (which I don’t see in the code that you’ve shared with us here); and (b) there are no scenarios where the view controller might be dismissed from some other mechanism not shown here.

But, I do wonder if the above could be reduced to the following:

```objectivec
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:self.coverVC animated:NO completion:^{
        [self showWindowWithImage:NO];
        
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                self.coverVC = nil;
                [self hideWindow];
            }];
        });
    }];
});
```

In short, just because you use a completion handler block, does not mean that you must use `weakSelf` pattern. We generally only do that when there is an actual strong reference cycle risk. I do not see any such risk here.

But, if you contemplate this sort of change, you really need to test it to make sure you have not introduced any new strong reference cycles (i.e., use “debug memory graph” debugger feature) and/or contemplated some alternate flows where the view controller was dismissed prematurely. I am not sure all of this development overhead is warranted just to eliminate those three lines of code. And all of this is assuming that you hadn’t simplified the code in the preparation of the example, hiding some other subtle strong reference cycle risk that is not shown in your question.

When dealing with legacy codebases, you have to weigh the benefit of the change against the development/testing overhead associated with that change. Personally, while the code screams “over-complicated” to me, I might ask whether this is the best use of your resources to validate the change.

Comment: Other than making the code look more complex, what is the downside of using the `weakSelf` pattern when it isn't needed?

Comment: @Rob thank you so much. That makes perfect sense. Unfortunately, the "new programmer" is me, I am self-taught and do this barely even part time, have one very old, large app, and haven't been able to even look at code in 4 plus years because I was caring for someone who was ill. But I really learned from what you said. I think I can do it with just self. I was actually looking at an answer of yours to another question on this just a few minutes ago. You have a great wealth of knowledge and quite a way of explaining things. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @SAHM – Well, no offense was intended. We’ve all been there. (Literally.) I’m glad you took it in the spirit intended.

Comment: Oh gosh, none taken. I really should be further along for how long I've been doing this. I'm just happy for the help. GCD has always been a little confusing to me.

Comment: @adamjansch – The downside is really negligible (hence my hesitancy to engage in the code change unless it was important). The performance change would be unobservable and we’re only talking about three extra lines of code. Sure, if I was doing a code review and saw this, I might tend to be extra cautious looking at the rest of the code. But that’s it. It’s not a “problem,” but rather just an unnecessary bit of code suggesting a conceptual misunderstanding on the part of the author.

Comment: @Rob out of curiosity, if I did need each of the strongSelf cases (i.e. if the code were different and the need was actually there), would it be proper to simply use the original strongSelf inside the second level of the nested block? I think this shows my understanding is still... weak. But I am trying.

Comment: @SAHM – It’s hard to say in the abstract whether you’d want one or two `strongSelf` references. It depends entirely upon the purpose of each of the two separate `strongSelf` references. But you could use two. (I can’t recall a practical, real-world case where I needed two; I frequently didn’t even need one.) But you could often get away with one. And you often don’t need any. (And if you were using it for nullability purposes, there were would be tests that it wasn’t null, too.)